# read message queue sent time from MSMQ Journal

Tags: c#, properties, message-queue, journal

I have an MSMQ with an enabled Journal. And due to the fact that we receive more than 1000 messages per day I want to clear the Journal to keep only the messages from last 2 days. Therfore I want to read all messages and check their SentTime property against the "current date - 2 days". But at the moment the program will stop as the Property SentTime wont be provided.

Error: "PropertyFilter isn't set correctly"

The code:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string queueName = ".\\private$\\TEST;journal";

        MessageQueue msgQueue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
        Message[] messages = msgQueue.GetAllMessages();

        try{

            foreach (Message msg in messages){
                //if(msg.SentTime < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2)){
                    Console.WriteLine(msg.SentTime);
                //}
            }

        }catch (Exception e){

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        }

        Console.Read();

    }

}
```

Why do I have no access to the Property?
Who can help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can answer my question by myself. The property filter will be set by: 

    msgQueue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SentTime = true;

Thats all!

Comment: Thanks for ur Question also for your answer...

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
msgQueue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll();
```

and it will set all filter properties to true.

Comment: Phew... been scratching my head with that one!